# If I do not know the number of words in a line then how do I use cut such a way that I get the last word?

Tags: bash, terminal

**for a file file.txt, the contents are:**

```
Had repulsive dashwoods suspicion sincerity but advantage now him. 
Remark easily garret nor nay.
Civil those mrs enjoy shy fat merry. You greatest jointure saw horrible.
He private he on be imagine suppose.
Fertile beloved evident through no service elderly is.
```

Now I want to cut such a way that I only get the last words of the lines

I tried

```
cut -d" " -f1- file.txt
```

but that just gives all from start to end.

```
cut -d" " -f-1 file.txt
```

This just gives the first word.

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 3):

You can do that easily with `awk`:

```
echo "Hi there Zeeshan." | awk '{print $NF}'
```

would print `Zeeshan.`

For your file:

```
awk '{print $NF}' file.txt
```

Comment: or with GNU awk: `echo "Hi there Zeeshan." | awk -F '[ .]' '{print $(NF-1)}'`